# How to make Javers compare by field values rather than ID/object reference

Tags: javers

I have an object like:

```
class Person {
    Phone phone;
}

class Phone {
    String number;
    String prefix;
    Phone(String n, String p) {
        number = n;
        prefix = p;
    }
}

Now consider this code:

Person p = new Person();
p.phone = new Phone("444444", "01");
javers.commit(p);
p.phone = new Phone("555555", "01");
javers.commit(p);
```

In this case sees that the reference of `Phone` has changed. While that's good info, I don't really care about that. I just want to know when the value of the `number` field has changed, that's really what I am tracking.

How would I achieve that? I tried defining the Phone class as a ValueObject, but it doesn't seem to do the job, I still get it as reference change rather than value change in the resulting `Commit` snapshot. Should I register it as a Value instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map Phone as ValueObject or let JaVers to apply default mapping, which is also ValueObject object. ValueObject are always compared property by property and never by reference. What do you mean by it doesn't seem to do the job?

Comment: To be honest I don't remember what "it doesn't seem to work' meant. I think that maybe I misunderstood how Javers works at the time. My guess is that at the time I thought that it's either reference change or value change. While I Javers does both - if the reference has changed, it'll log that, but also if the value has changed, given the new reference has the same ID. I don't have any issues at the moment, all seems to work fine.